# Using ADC on Teensy 3.6

Tags: c++, arduino, sampling, adc, teensy

I am trying to port a program I created on an Arduino Mega onto a Teensy 3.6. I used a clip of code I found to sample an audio signal and then run fast Fourier transform over it, but now that I am porting it the Teensy doesn't accept the way they collected the audio samples on the Arduino. Can I use AnalogRead to get the same effect? How can I port this code over to work the same way? What is this code doing when it says it is "// clear ADIF bit so that ADC can do next operation (0xf5)" and do I need to port this over as well? Thank you

```
void setup() {

    ADCSRA = 0b11100110;      // set ADC to free running mode and set pre-scalar to 32 (0xe5)

    ADMUX = 0b00000000;       // use pin A0 and external voltage reference
}


void loop() {
   // ++ Sampling

   for(int i=0; i<SAMPLES; i++)
    {
      while(!(ADCSRA & 0x10));        // wait for ADC to complete current conversion ie ADIF bit set
      ADCSRA = 0b11110101 ;               // clear ADIF bit so that ADC can do next operation (0xf5)
      int value = ADC - 512 ;                 // Read from ADC and subtract DC offset caused value
      vReal[i]= value/4;                      // Copy to bins after compressing
      vImag[i] = 0;                         
    }
    // -- Sampling
}
```

This code works perfectly on the Arduino Mega, but the Teensy gives me the error:

```
Teensy_Version: In function 'void setup()':
Teensy_Version:57: error: 'ADCSRA' was not declared in this scope
     ADCSRA = 0b11100110;      // set ADC to free running mode and set pre-scalar to 32 (0xe5)
 ^
Teensy_Version:59: error: 'ADMUX' was not declared in this scope
     ADMUX = 0b00000000;       // use pin A0 and external voltage reference
 ^
Teensy_Version: In function 'void loop()':
Teensy_Version:106: error: 'ADCSRA' was not declared in this scope
       while(!(ADCSRA & 0x10));        // wait for ADC to complete current conversion ie ADIF bit set
           ^
Teensy_Version:107: error: 'ADCSRA' was not declared in this scope
       ADCSRA = 0b11110101 ;               // clear ADIF bit so that ADC can do next operation (0xf5)
   ^
Teensy_Version:108: error: 'ADC' was not declared in this scope
       int value = ADC - 512 ;                 // Read from ADC and subtract DC offset caused value
               ^
```

Answer (score 2):

An Arduino Mega's MCU is an ATmega2560 while the Teensy 3.6's is a Arm Cortex M4.

ADCSRA and similar abbreviations address registers of the ATmega2560 which do not even exist on the Arm Cortex M4. That's a completly different architecture.

Comment: Ok, do you know of where I can find the registers for the Arm Cortex M4? Or can I simply use AnalogRead to solve the issue?

Comment: @SpencerBrennessel  In its manual. Understand what the Arduino code does and implement it on the Teensy. You cannot simply run Arduino code on a Teensy. If you insist you might try something like teensyduino.

Answer (score 0):

AnalogRead works for simple applications. If you need more control over the ADC [pevides ADC library](https://github.com/pedvide/ADC) is commonly used. It doesn't require you to go down to the register level.